# Is this a good way to make my footer sticky in all situations?

Tags: php, html, css

I am still kind of new to HTML and CSS, so I wanted to ask if this is a good way to make my footer always stick to the bottom without overlapping with anything. I also included some PHP to make my work easier and just require the header and footer on each webpage.

Here is what I have:

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Начало - Гравиране Провадия</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        require_once 'requires/header.html';
        ?>
        SAMPLE CONTENT, blah blah.
        <?php
        require_once 'requires/footer.html';
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

**footer.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <style>
            html {
                height: 100%;
            }
            body {
                min-height: 100%;
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
            }
            footer {
                background: #A6FF46;
                font-family: 'Roboto';
                text-align: center;
                padding: 0.5rem;
                margin-top: auto;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <footer>
            Copyright &copy; 2022, Gravirane Provadia. All rights reserved.
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If that really is your HTML contents, you are write it wrong! It will becomes multiple open `<!doctype html>` and contains `<html>`, `<head>`, etc inside `<body>` which is invalid! Just only `<footer>` in your footer.html is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `position: fixed;`? That creates it so that the element will always 'stick' to the position you set it to using `left: position;`,`bottom: position;`,etc.

Comment: Hi! I saw that this is a possible fix, but I haven't tried it yet. Does that mean that I do not need any of the html, body and margin-top CSS? I am sorry if this is a stupid question, however like I said above, I am still quite new to this. Haha.

Comment: I don't think you should need the HTML, body and margin-top CSS, but you will need to try it.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your help. I will try experimenting with it.

Comment: Hello again, it worked better than I thought, however a new issue showed up. Whatever content I have on the webpage, the header and footer overlap it. Is there a way to make it so that the content is below the header and above the footer?

Comment: You might need to use `margin-top: height of header;` and `margin-bottom: height of footer;` in the main index.php file inside a style tag. That might help.